# Polite alternatives to “Whatever you say”

Tags: phrase-requests, politeness, synonyms

I wish to convey that “I will comply with your request, because I have to, although I am extremely offended that you made such a request.’ in a  more concise (or passive aggressive) phrase. How?

I am aiming for something diplomatic, witty and or clever rather than sarcastic.

Comment: Roll your eyes while saying "Whatever."  If you're not sure how this looks, ask a teenager to do something.

Comment: Most of that will be most effectively conveyed by tone and delivery, where delivery includes emphasis, facial expressions, posture, gestures, etc. That said, "as you wish", "will do", and "consider it done" work. The last is probably my favorite, because I haven't said I'll do it, and so reserve the option of not doing it.

Answer (score 1):

> If I must.
>
> So be it.
>
> If that is really what you want...
>
> Is that an order?
>
> [laugh out loud, then pretend to notice only now that the request was serious, with exaggerated facial expressions] Oh, you were serious. Uhh, okay.
>
> I will of course do as you say, but please record my formal objection in case there will be an investigation. [drum rolls]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this is a work situation or something private, perhaps in a relationship. Therefore I will assume it is a work situation.

Obligation compels me to do as you say, and quite frankly, getting home before dark scares me silly.